# Remove port from custom local domain in vue devServer

Tags: vue.js, webpack

So I have a vue project where I want to acces the application without the port showing, when developing local, so it could look like this:

```
local.mycoolsite.com
```

My etc/hosts look like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost local.mycoolsite.com
```

and my vue.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'local.mycoolsite.com',
    public: 'local.mycoolsite.com',
    port: 9001,
  }
}
```

running the app outputs these domains:

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://local.mycoolsite.com:9001/ 
  - Network: http://local.mycoolsite.com/
```

When i access `local.mycoolsite.com` i get this
[image]

Does anyone have suggestion ?
and thanks you for taken the time

Comment: Use 80/443 port for development, or you'll need to set up Nginx or Apache locally.

Comment: So when i set port to 80 or 443 VUE defaults the port to 1024, so i guess i have to spin up Nginx or Apache. Thank you and praise the sun!